# Program type already present: org.apache.http.auth.AuthSchemeFactory

Tags: android, gradle

I used [Picasso](https://github.com/square/picasso) as dependency for both the my App project and the chat library

Here is the error I'm facing while compiling the code:

> Program type already present: org.apache.http.auth.AuthSchemeFactory
>   Message{kind=ERROR, text=Program type already present:
>
> org.apache.http.auth.AuthSchemeFactory, sources=[Unknown source file], tool name=Optional.of(D8)}

so how to use same dependency for two project?

```
---- Root project----  
                    |
                    |
                    ---app
                    |
                    ---chat library
```

**EDIT Saturday - 2018 14 April**

in app>libs folder the following `jar` files exist:

- httpclient-4.3.6
- httpcore-4.3.3
- httpmime-4.3.6

Comment: did this issue got resolved ?

Answer (score 4):

I had have the same issue. As the first you can see that a new dexer called **D8** is running. It seems to be still experimental so you can switch it off temporally in *gradle.properties* file by:

```
android.enableD8=false
```

See more details about D8 in a [blog announcement](https://android-developers.googleblog.com/2018/04/android-studio-switching-to-d8-dexer.html)

Then you can see more detailed error message which led me to following solution:

```
implementation("org.apache.oltu.oauth2:org.apache.oltu.oauth2.client:1.0.1") {
    exclude group: 'org.apache.oltu.oauth2', module: org.apache.oltu.oauth2.common'
}
```

Comment: The option 'android.enableD8' is deprecated and should not be used anymore.
Use 'android.enableD8=true' to remove this warning.
It will be removed in AGP version 3.3.