# My gradle build is not running after updating the android project in android studio

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle

> Android source code not running after updating project. It gives below error.
>
> **Program type already present: org.apache.http.auth.AuthSchemeProvider
>   Message{kind=ERROR, text=Program type already present: org.apache.http.auth.AuthSchemeProvider, sources=[Unknown source file], tool name=Optional.of(D8)}**

```
dependencies {
implementation fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
implementation('com.github.danysantiago:sendgrid-android:1', {
    exclude group: 'org.apache.httpcomponents.httpclient-android'
    exclude group: 'org.apache.httpcomponents.httpclient'
})

implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.1.1'
implementation 'com.android.support:design:27.1.1'
implementation 'com.android.support:support-v4:27.1.1'
implementation 'com.github.mancj:MaterialSearchBar:0.6'
// Glide image library
implementation 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:3.7.0'
implementation 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:27.1.1'
implementation 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.5.2'
implementation 'com.makeramen:roundedimageview:2.2.1'
implementation 'io.card:android-sdk:5.5.0'
implementation 'com.roughike:bottom-bar:2.1.1'
implementation 'com.kaopiz:kprogresshud:1.0.5'
implementation 'com.jude:swipebackhelper:3.1.2'
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-analytics:8.4.0'
implementation 'com.journeyapps:zxing-android-embedded:3.2.0@aar'
implementation 'com.google.zxing:core:3.2.1'
implementation 'com.xwray:passwordview:1.0'
implementation 'com.github.javiersantos:AppUpdater:2.6.4'
/*implementation 'com.sun.mail:android-mail:1.5.5'
    implementation 'com.sun.mail:android-activation:1.5.5'*/
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:8.4.0'
implementation 'it.sephiroth.android.library.targettooltip:target-tooltip-library:1.3.15'
implementation 'com.stripe:stripe-android:6.0.0'
implementation 'org.altbeacon:android-beacon-library:2.12.4'
implementation files('libs/volley.jar')
implementation 'com.shawnlin:number-picker:2.4.6'
implementation('com.crashlytics.sdk.android:crashlytics:2.6.6@aar') {
    transitive = true;
}
implementation project(':NPLibrary')
```

}

Comment: did you try this fix https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49834773/program-type-already-present-org-apache-http-auth-authschemefactory?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to add this line

```
implementation('com.github.danysantiago:sendgrid-android:1', {
    exclude group: 'org.apache.httpcomponents.httpclient-android'
    exclude group: 'org.apache.httpcomponents.httpclient'
    //add this line
    exclude group: 'org.apache.http.auth'
})
```

**Update 1**

Remove this line

```
implementation files('libs/volley.jar')
```

Because you have already specified.

```
implementation fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
```

Comment: `implementation files` doesn't conflict with `implementation fileTree`

Answer (score 0):

if you have updated your android studio I've gotta say, there are some serious issues with new version of Android Studio, try this for starter

upgrade:

```
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-analytics:8.4.0'
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:8.4.0'
```

to:

```
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-analytics:12.0.1'
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:12.0.1'
```

then check your project level Gradle and add this line with exact same version:

```
classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.2.0'
```

hope it help you out.