# Android: Java Library build fail due to transformDexArchiveWithExternalLibsDexMergerForDebug Program type already present

Tags: java, android, android-studio, gradle, android-gradle-plugin

I'm trying to compile [Leshan Server Demo](https://github.com/eclipse/leshan/tree/master/leshan-server-demo) as Java library into Android Studio, because I'd like to use it into an application.

When I'm compiling it I'm having one library that it's included that define a particular class, that is also defined by another class, included as well into the project. Both libraries are necessary.

This is my gradle file

```
apply plugin: 'java-library'
    
sourceCompatibility = "8"
targetCompatibility = "8"
    
dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    implementation 'org.slf4j:slf4j-android:1.7.25'
    implementation 'com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-databind:2.9.8'
    implementation 'org.jmdns:jmdns:3.5.5'
    implementation 'commons-cli:commons-cli:1.4'
    implementation 'org.eclipse.californium:californium-core:2.0.0-M13'
    implementation 'org.eclipse.jetty:jetty-webapp:9.4.14.v20181114'
    implementation 'org.eclipse.jetty:jetty-continuation:9.4.14.v20181114'
    implementation 'commons-io:commons-io:2.6'
    implementation 'org.apache.commons:commons-lang3:3.8.1'
    implementation 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.8.5'
    implementation 'org.eclipse.leshan:leshan-server-cf:1.0.0-M10'
    implementation 'org.eclipse.leshan:leshan-server-cluster:1.0.0-M10'
}
```

The sources are currently identical to the file in their github repository (linked above)

If I try to compile I have:

> Task :app:transformDexArchiveWithExternalLibsDexMergerForDebug FAILED
>
> AGPBI: {"kind":"error","text":"Program type already present: org.eclipse.leshan.server.cluster.RedisRegistrationStore","sources":[{}],"tool":"D8"}

As far as I know it means that two libraries are defining the same class: RedisRegistrationStore

What I'd like to do is to exclude it in some way.

Looking on different solution found here such as [Similar solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49834773/program-type-already-present-org-apache-http-auth-authschemefactory) , I've tried to make some exclusions, and I've modified the gradle file in this way:

```
........
    implementation 'org.eclipse.leshan:leshan-server-cluster:1.0.0-M10'{
    exclude group: 'org.eclipse.leshan', module:'cluster'
}
........
```

but maybe it means that I'm not able to make exclusions, because I get this other error

> Could not find method org.eclipse.leshan:leshan-server-cluster:1.0.0-M10() for arguments [build_cbo5jg18zhz8pvdsjliwvve5w$_run_closure1$_closure2@428dc770] on object of type org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.dsl.dependencies.DefaultDependencyHandler.

Btw I'm not sure that the exclusion of a group/module is the correct approach to my problem. I just need to remove one class.

I've also taken a look here: [Android doc how to fix duplicate classes](https://developer.android.com/studio/build/dependencies#duplicate_classes)

But it does not fit my problem, because my class is declared into the lib A and into the lib B, and not as direct dependency as in the official documentation

Do you have an idea how to proceed in my case and maybe in general what is the best approach to fix this problem?

And what am I doing wrong?

**EDIT**

This is my dependencies tree

```
+--- org.slf4j:slf4j-android:1.7.25
|    \--- org.slf4j:slf4j-api:1.7.25
+--- com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-databind:2.9.8
|    +--- com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-annotations:2.9.0
|    \--- com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-core:2.9.8
+--- org.jmdns:jmdns:3.5.5
|    \--- org.slf4j:slf4j-api:1.7.25
+--- commons-cli:commons-cli:1.4
+--- org.eclipse.californium:californium-core:2.0.0-M13
|    +--- org.eclipse.californium:californium-legal:2.0.0-M13
|    +--- org.eclipse.californium:element-connector:2.0.0-M13
|    |    +--- org.eclipse.californium:californium-legal:2.0.0-M13
|    |    \--- org.slf4j:slf4j-api:1.7.25
|    \--- org.slf4j:slf4j-api:1.7.25
+--- org.eclipse.jetty:jetty-webapp:9.4.14.v20181114
|    +--- org.eclipse.jetty:jetty-xml:9.4.14.v20181114
|    |    \--- org.eclipse.jetty:jetty-util:9.4.14.v20181114
|    \--- org.eclipse.jetty:jetty-servlet:9.4.14.v20181114
|         \--- org.eclipse.jetty:jetty-security:9.4.14.v20181114
|              \--- org.eclipse.jetty:jetty-server:9.4.14.v20181114
|                   +--- javax.servlet:javax.servlet-api:3.1.0
|                   +--- org.eclipse.jetty:jetty-http:9.4.14.v20181114
|                   |    +--- org.eclipse.jetty:jetty-util:9.4.14.v20181114
|                   |    \--- org.eclipse.jetty:jetty-io:9.4.14.v20181114
|                   |         \--- org.eclipse.jetty:jetty-util:9.4.14.v20181114
|                   \--- org.eclipse.jetty:jetty-io:9.4.14.v20181114 (*)
+--- org.eclipse.jetty:jetty-continuation:9.4.14.v20181114
+--- commons-io:commons-io:2.6
+--- org.apache.commons:commons-lang3:3.8.1
+--- com.google.code.gson:gson:2.8.5
+--- org.eclipse.leshan:leshan-server-cf:1.0.0-M10
|    +--- org.eclipse.leshan:leshan-core-cf:1.0.0-M10
|    |    +--- org.eclipse.leshan:leshan-core:1.0.0-M10
|    |    |    +--- org.slf4j:slf4j-api:1.7.25
|    |    |    \--- com.eclipsesource.minimal-json:minimal-json:0.9.5
|    |    +--- org.eclipse.californium:californium-core:2.0.0-M12 -> 2.0.0-M13 (*)
|    |    \--- org.eclipse.californium:scandium:2.0.0-M12
|    |         +--- org.eclipse.californium:element-connector:2.0.0-M12 -> 2.0.0-M13 (*)
|    |         \--- org.slf4j:slf4j-api:1.7.25
|    +--- org.eclipse.leshan:leshan-server-core:1.0.0-M10
|    |    \--- org.eclipse.leshan:leshan-core:1.0.0-M10 (*)
|    +--- org.eclipse.californium:californium-core:2.0.0-M12 -> 2.0.0-M13 (*)
|    \--- org.eclipse.californium:scandium:2.0.0-M12 (*)
\--- org.eclipse.leshan:leshan-server-cluster:1.0.0-M10
     +--- org.eclipse.leshan:leshan-core:1.0.0-M10 (*)
     +--- org.eclipse.leshan:leshan-server-cf:1.0.0-M10 (*)
     +--- redis.clients:jedis:2.8.0
     |    \--- org.apache.commons:commons-pool2:2.3
     +--- com.eclipsesource.minimal-json:minimal-json:0.9.5
     +--- commons-cli:commons-cli:1.3.1 -> 1.4
     \--- ch.qos.logback:logback-classic:1.2.3
          +--- ch.qos.logback:logback-core:1.2.3
          \--- org.slf4j:slf4j-api:1.7.25
```

Answer (score 0):

try to add this line

```
implementation "com.android.support:design:${rootProject.ext.supportLibVersion}"
```

or you can use this also

```
implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.1.0'

implementation 'com.android.support:design:27.1.0'
```

Comment: unfortunately it's still not working with the same error "Program type already present"